# Most efficient way to query across partition with CosmosDB for bulk operations

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a cross partition query that returns the rows for each partition in turn, which makes sense, all of partition 1’s results, all of partition 2’s etc.

For each row returned I need to perform an action, could be a delete or update.

There are too many records to read them all in and then perform the actions, so I need to stream in the results and perform the actions at the same time.

The issue I get is I run out of RU very quickly as my actions get run on each partition in turn and a single partition has a tenth of the RUs allocated.

I can specify a `PartitionKey` in the `FeedOptions` but that does not help me as I don’t know what the key will be.

My query looks like

```
select r.* from r where r.deleted
```

the `partition` is on a field called `container`

Imagine I have the following items

```
container|title    |deleted
jamjar   |jam      |true      <--- stored in partition 5
jar      |pickles  |true      <--- stored in partition 5
tin      |cookies  |true      <--- stored in partition 8
tub      |sweets   |true      <--- stored in partition 9
```

I do `select r.title from r where r.deleted`
my query will return the rows in the following order

```
jam      <--- stored in partition 5
pickles  <--- stored in partition 5
cookies  <--- stored in partition 8
sweets   <--- stored in partition 9
```

I use an `ActionBlock` to allow me to spin up 2 threads to do my action on each row returned, so I work on `jam`  and `pickles` then `cookies` and `sweets` thus consuming RUs from partion 5 when I am carrying out the action on `jam` and `pickles`

I would like the results to be returned as:

```
jam      <--- stored in partition 5
cookies  <--- stored in partition 8
sweets   <--- stored in partition 9
pickles  <--- stored in partition 5
```

For normal API calls we always know the `container`, this is a requirement for a bulk and very infrequent delete.

If know the number of partition and could supply the partition number to the query that would be fine, I would be happy to issue 10 query and just treat this as 10 separate jobs.

Comment: you can run query `SELECT DISTINCT c.container FROM c where c.deleted = true` to select all partitions with deleted items and then run stored procedure which delete in bulk docs for each partition

Comment: I examples may be misleading, I can read all the data, the issue is, it uses all the RUs on each partition in order rather than returned a few rows for each in the initial select.

Comment: my guess, it's according to how the partitions designed inside cosmos. So, each doc with partition in the same partition key range is located in the same physical location. That's why when use query cross-partition you will see the result from one physical location first, then others. To solve your problem, you could write own manager that will distribute load over partitions on client side.

Comment: cosmos just handles the partitions on its own, and this is fine for normal use, its just my one off bulk operation  that is hindered . I have just re-read one of the docs and I think I need todo this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-partition-data#parallel-query-execution (which I am sure I tried before :) )

Comment: I set the `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` option and use fiddler to see what happens, and I can see it issuing 10 requests and setting a header that looks like its something todo with the Partition -- I have answered it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` which is part of the `FeedOptions` :

```
FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions
{
   EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
   MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10,
};
```

It will create a client thread for each partion, you can see what is happening if you inpsect the HTTP Headers

```
x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition: True
x-ms-documentdb-query-parallelizecrosspartitionquery: True
x-ms-documentdb-populatequerymetrics: False
x-ms-documentdb-partitionkeyrangeid: QQlvANNcKgA=,3
```

Notice the **QQlvANNcKgA=,3** you see 10 of these with **,0** through to **,9** i suspect the first part is some page tracking and the second part is the partition

See the docs [Parallel query execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-partition-data#parallel-query-execution)

Here's the timeline view of 3 queries in Fiddler:

- `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10`: slower and not quite parallel, while the threads and connections are spun up (you can see the 5 extra SSL handshakes in the listing on the left, and a gap before the last 5 requests of the 'green' set in the timeline). There are also 2 (for some reason) requests to get the PK ranges for the collection
- `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10` (again) : almost optimally parallel. The PK range info seems to be cached from the previous request and reused here without making any extraneous requests.
- `MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 0`: completely sequential.
  Interestingly, these requests don't specify a `x-ms-documentdb-partitionkeyrangeid` header.

The query is run against a collection with **6** physical partitions, using DocumentClient v2.x.

Notice also that 7 requests are fired for every query, the 1st one is a 'query plan request' (not parallelizable) while the following 6 return the actual data.

[image]

Comment: Empirically, the first part (that looks like a Base64 string) is the internal id (aka `_rid`) of the *collection*. It should always be the same for all queries against that collection.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my editing your answer (feel free to revert if you do). There's no easy way to embed an image in the comment, and I didn't want to post a separate answer without sufficient context, or duplicating your content.